# How to guarantee that a class is implementing a particular interface in C#

Tags: c#, interface

I'd like to make an interface that depends on the functionality of another interface. For instance, I'm making:

```
interface IHealth  {

}

interface IHealthBar {

}
```

An entity that attaches `IHealthBar` will need an `IHealth` as a prerequisite. How do I declare that in C#?

---

**Update**

Inheritance is not the answer here. The Health bar relies on one piece of information from Health, not it's entire implementation. `IHealth` HAS A health bar, `IHealthBar` is NOT A Health.

Comment: "`IHealthBar` will need an `IHealth`" - (besides all the answers dealing with inheritance) this could also be understood to mean that `IHealthBar` needs a *property* of type `IHealth`, so basically: `interface IHealthBar { IHealth Health { get; } }`

Comment: Btw. from the naming it seems like the purpose of `IHealthBar` is to *display* an `IHealth` object. Which would further my point that this should probably *not* be an "IS A" relation and more a "HAS A".

Comment: Id rather not use inheritance, this is the best answer I've seen yet. Id mark it as correct if it were an answer.

Comment: Your question would likely be much clearer if you showed an example class using these two interfaces, so that we can see what behavior you want to create.  Your description in words, without code, is apparently not sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IHealth HAS A health bar, IHealthBar is NOT A Health.

Ok then make `IHealth` have a health bar

```
interface IHealth  {
    IHealthBar HealthBar {get;}
}
```

This makes any implementer of `IHealth` have a public getter for a property called `HealthBar` of type `IHealthBar`, it is up to the implementer how he wants to handle the setter.

```
public class Monster : IHealth
{
    public Monster()
    {
        HealthBar = new MonserHealthBar();
    }

    public IHealthBar HealthBar {get; private set;}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

derive/extend from the other interface, like so...

```
interface IHealthBar : IHealth {

}
```

**As a side note**, you can also have **multiple inheritance** for `interfaces` in C#, so if you were only looking to break up the interface definitions, you could could create classes that did something like...

```
public class OnlyNeedHealth : IHealth {}
public class NeedHealthAndHealthBar : IHealth, IHealthBar {}
```

Comment: Inheritance is not the solution here. A health bar and health are separate components.

Comment: @JoshElias, I am not saying this is the answer, hence **side note**, I was just highlighting that you can have multiple interface inheritance if you wanted to!

Comment: @JoshElias: You failed to explain in your question why they are separate. Because if `IHealthBar` requires the implementing class to also implement `IHealth`, they are obviously not separate. You may want to greatly improve your question by showing your actual use case.

Comment: If you don't think that this is the answer then why is it posted as an answer?

Comment: @JoshElias, I was referring to the **side note**, I guess your suggesting that this `interface IHealthBar : IHealth` is incorrect?

Comment: I don't believe it's the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Make `IHealthBar` derive from `IHealth`:

```
public interface IHealth
{
}

public interface IHealthBar : IHealth
{
}
```

Comment: @Josh this is correct - think about it, how can an entity have a health bar if it doesn't have health? This will insure that relationship is maintained.

Comment: Whoever is responsible for downvoting all answers here: Please leave a comment as to why.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the interface inherit from one another:

```
interface IHealthBar : IHealth
{
  /// ...
}
```